# How to add ssl in my website with shared hosting?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, shared-hosting

I want to enable ssl in my website which is developed in ASP.NET MVC and hosted on a shared server.

How can I enable ssl? I don't know how to enable ssl.

Comment: Did you read this article http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis

Comment: @RockOnGom I had read the article but did not understand. Can you tell me the steps to enable ssl in shared hosting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to purchase the SSL from you Shared hosting provider only, Because you not owner of the shared server, your hosting provider should do this for you.

Please check with your hosting provider they should have option for this. In godaddy or other major hosting provider this option online. where you can login to your account and avail SSL facility paying extra amount.